# Finding the size of a dataset based on the size of the scrollbar

Tags: macros, size, scrollbar, autohotkey

So this one is sort of a language agnostic question that I don't really know what kinds of tags to use to sort it....

Essentially I have a program that is autopopulating to a flex app.   The flex app is basically a frame with options that load in a main content area.   The amount that you can click on is dependent on a variety of factors and can range from 1-13000 based on these factors.

I'm writing a macro using AHK to perform an action on all of these items.  But without knowing the exact number of items in the list I am unable to do much about it.   To make matters worse I am entirely unable to find any documentation on this anywhere else.

Example below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAVHi.jpg

I'm going to file this under macros, I would love it if someone can help me with other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would certainly NOT base a calculation on the size of the scrollbar. What if there is no scrollbar? There is most likely no scrollbar for only a few items.

If you can determine the size of the scrollbar programmatically, why can you not determine how many rows are in the grid programmatically?

Comment: Because to scroll down there is absolutely no way to check the data for uniqueness.   Lets say I have a dataset of 5000, if I can use the side of the scrollbar in pixels to better determine the size it will help me prevent duplicates at the end of my test.

At present I can have the action hit every object, but I can't have it not duplicate at the end when the scrollbar hits the bottom.

Comment: Damien, I like your way of thinking about the scroll-bar, you could even think about how far the scroll-bar went down after e.g. 3 PgDn's. However, using the scroll-bar will be a challenge I think. Do I understand that you could work your way all the way to the last record, but you need to know when you hit the last record? I.e. if you read the last record and it is the same as the previously read record, you know you hit rock bottom?

Comment: No you can't my earlier idea to use the position of the scroll-bar after 3 PgDn's because if there is only one page the scroll bar would not move and give you the impression of an infinitely long list.....